# Pivot_longer on integer and factor

Tags: r, pivot, tidyr

I have a dataset that looks like the following.

```
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  hhm1q001 hhm2q001 hhm1q002 hhm2q002
  <chr>    <chr>    <int>    <int>   
1 blue     red      30       50
```

I have been trying to transform it to long using  `tidyr::pivot_longer`
my expected output looks like this:

```
  hhm   q001  q002 
  <int> <chr> <int>
1 1     blue  30   
2 2     red   50
```

I have tried the following code

```
HHS_long <- pivot_longer(HHS_all, 
                         cols= starts_with("hhm"), #identifies the column from which to go from wide to long
                         names_to = ("hhm"), #name(s) of new column(s) created from cols= 
                         values_drop_na = FALSE
)
head(HHS_long)
```

Unfortunately i get the following error 
`.Error: No common type for hhm1q101 <factor<b5064>> and hhm1q102 <integer>.`

Not sure how to go around this, i get they are not the same class, but i have quite a lot of variable in the dataset and they are definitely of a different class.
Hope this is the correct format to posting.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `pivot_longer` of `tidyr` and whether it would be able to do so. Using a combination of `tidyr::separate` and the `melt` and `cast` verbs from `reshape2` I was able to produce your expected output:

```
df <- data.frame(hhm1q001 = "blue", hhm2q001 = "red", hhm1q002 = 30, hhm2q002=  50 )

df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  reshape2::melt(id.vars = "id") %>% 
  tidyr::separate(variable, into = c("hhm", "q00"), sep = 4) %>% 
  tidyr::separate(hhm, into = c("prefix", "hhm"), sep = 3) %>% 
  select(-prefix, -id) %>% 
  reshape2::dcast(hhm ~ q00)
```

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, 

I was trying with gather/spread first, but they are deprecated in the new `tidyr` version and replaced by `tidyr::pivot_wider` and `pivot_longer` which from a beginners point of view are a lot easier to understand.

Similarly, could you walk me through your input?
Reshape seems very powerful but a bit abscond, and also why do i need to first melt (make longer?) before widening (dcast?) the dataset?
Thanks

Comment: The melt function transforms your dataframe into a long format, with one value for each variable. Consequently, I separate the variables to split the values and the names, in two steps. I suggest you run the pipe each step at a time to study the output. Lastly, I remove the unneeded columns and cast it back to the wide format you requested.

Comment: In the end I used a variation of your code to reach the expected results.
My dataframe was a lot more complicated and irregular than the example I provided, but the base was there. 
After some tinkering, it worked out great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I struggle a little bit when I use the new `pivot_longer`. Sometimes, I feel that renaming variable names before `pivot_longer` could make it much easier:

```
library(tidyverse)
HHS_all <- data.frame(hhm1q001 =  "blue", hhm2q001 =  "red", hhm1q002 = 30, hhm2q002 = 50)

df <- HHS_all %>% 
  rename(q001hhm1 = hhm1q001, q001hhm2 = hhm2q001, 
         q002hhm1 = hhm1q002, q002hhm2 = hhm2q002) 

df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = c(".value", "hhm"), names_sep = "hhm")
```

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  hhm   q001   q002
  <chr> <fct> <dbl>
1 1     blue     30
2 2     red      50
```

Comment: Thanks for sticking to the new tidyr functions.
I don't know if it is a bug or what, but when i used pivot_wider /longer on a big dataframe; i end up with <chr> or <dbl> or <null> instead of the actual values.
From some research i understood it has to do with the type of object pivot_* creates. 
Have you ever faced this?

Comment: I am actually a struggling `r` learner myself. I have not faced this in my work. I guess other more experienced users might be able to help if you provide more information.